# f1-micro shuts down instance with high CPU usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I use f1-micro mainly for main dev environment, I connect to the instance using vscode ssh extension. But whenever I try to open a medium sized javascript file, or an extension loading up in the background, the ssh connection always timed out.

I've tried replacing the instance, but no luck, the ssh connection always reset.

Comment: Have you tried using other machine type or it just happen to F1? from what I understand f1 is share core VM. Also, do you have a static external IP on your VM?

Comment: I never triy any other machine yet. I have my instance IP reserved as a static external IP. I will give another machine type a try and let see what happens.